# How to manage Virtual repo in artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I am using artifactory with 5.x version and I added http://repo1.maven.org/ as repo1 to my remote repo. But from my artifactory,  But I am unable to download some of the artifacts from apache which is from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache. How can I allow artifactory to download artifacts from apache folder.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of data. What do you have defined in your Maven settings file for resolution? Which virtual repository are you using for the aggregation? Have you added the 'repo1' repository to the virtual repository used for the resolution? Have you looked in the JFrog Artifactory wiki page for virtual repositories configurations:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories

Comment: thanks @Ariel. I have solved this issue giving it complete permissions on that repo to myself and also modified repo patterns in admin/remote/modified repo by including Ant pattern. thanks....